# listen for "open file with my java application" event on windows

Tags: java, install4j, file-association

Title is confusing, but don't know how to explain this in a few words:

I have a java application that reads *.example files. I've also added a file association thanks to `install4j` so my application is launched when the user double clicks any file with extension *.example

It seems that install4j sends the file path in the `args[]` so it should be easy to open that file and show it in my app. **BUT** what happens if the app is already running? I can only allow one instance of the application so, how can I know that the user is opening a file?

I've found this: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/launcher/StartupNotification.html

But I still don't understand how should I use it and what should I add in my app to listen for this event. Where can I find an example?

Comment: If you cannot find a solution via Install4J, there is always [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The [file services demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) shows how to use it for initial launch, as well as when a new file is opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation you linked to, it looks like you can do this:

```
StartupNotification.registerStartupListener(new StartupNotification.Listener() {
    public void startupPerformed(String parameters) {
        System.out.println("Startup performed with parameters " + parameters);
    }
});
```

Since `startupPerformed` will be called from different threads, you will need to make sure that the code that handles these notifications is thread-safe.

The documentation also says:

> For multiple files, files are surrounded by double-quotes and separated by spaces.

So you will need to parse the parameter string yourself as well.

Comment: sounds nice, I will try & accept tomorrow. Thank you @andrewdotn!!

Comment: it works =) I've added `i4jruntime.jar` as library for my project and used your sample code inside `main()`. The event is fired when the app is running and you open a file, and the `parameters` var contains the absolute path of the file.